# Custom x-axis scaling for specified ranges using "weights"

Tags: gnuplot

I have a series of numbers in a file that I can already plot using gnuplot.

The tricky question: I have a bunch of ranges (positions), like

```
1-11
12-50
51-500
500-512
```

From this I can calculate the length of the actual range. Based on this lenght, I want to dynamically scale the x-axis for that actual range. Bigger length should produce more "compression" on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. Does

```
set xrange [51:500]
```

do what you want?

Comment: I want to plot different sections with different "x axis density" because sometimes I have tons of similar rows that are less important to go in deep details. But I found the answer for this: http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot6-e.html#side All I have to do is to prepare the options for gnuplot in some script.